# Filtering in <sjg:grid> without case sensitivity

Tags: java, jqgrid, struts2

I'm using a struts2jquery grid in which I've given filter="true". So it's filtering the data in client side. But It's filtering only on case sensitivity. I need to get data without case. So what should I need to add for that. Expecting some suggestions. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution with javaScript :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sjg" uri="/struts-jquery-grid-tags"%>

   <s:url var="remoteurl" action="jsontable" />

    <sjg:grid id="gridtableID" 

        caption="Primjer JSON TABELE" 
        dataType="json"
        href="%{remoteurl}" 
        gridModel="gridModel" 
        viewrecords="true"
        pager="true"
        pagerPosition="centar"
        navigator="true"
        navigatorSearch="true"
        filter="true"
        filterOptions="{stringResult:true}"
        loadonce="true"

         >

        <sjg:gridColumn name="id"
            index="id" title="ID" 
            formatter="integer"
            search="false"
            searchoptions="{sopt:['cn','eq','ne','bw','bn','ew','en','nc']}"
            editable="false" />
        <sjg:gridColumn name="name" index="name" title="Name" sortable="true"
            search="true"
            searchoptions="{sopt:['cn','eq','ne','bw','bn','ew','en','nc']}" />
        <sjg:gridColumn name="country" index="country" title="Country"
            search="true"
            searchoptions="{sopt:['cn','eq','ne','bw','bn','ew','en','nc']}"/>
        <sjg:gridColumn name="city" index="city" title="City" search="true"
            searchoptions="{sopt:['cn','eq','ne','bw','bn','ew','en','nc']}" />
        <sjg:gridColumn name="creditLimit" index="creditLimit"
            title="Credit Limit" formatter="currency" search="true"
            searchoptions="{sopt:['cn','eq','ne','bw','bn','ew','en','nc']}"/>

    </sjg:grid>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#gridtableID").jqGrid('setGridParam', { ignoreCase: true});
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit late but here's an easier solution:

Step 1:
Add onCompleteTopics to the sgj:grid tag.

```
<sjg:grid
...
onCompleteTopics="loadComplete"
...
>
```

Step 2:
Add .subscribe to your .jsp with the following code inside.

```
<script>
    $.subscribe('loadComplete', function (event, data){
         $("#gridtable").jqGrid('setGridParam', { ignoreCase: true});
    });
</script>
```

This should turn off case sensitivity on your filter row at the top of your grid. This is strictly for client-side filtering.